# Xcode 5.1 won't launch -- "being updated" -- but already installed

Tags: mac-appstore, xcode, software-update

trying to launch Xcode 5.1 and keep getting "Xcode is being updated". It was updated last week and shows as installed. Screen shots to illustrate. Any ideas? I went to the developer portal, but it takes you to the App Store (I was hoping there was a seperate install). Many thanks. Project is stuck at the moment.

[image: Xcode is being updated]

[image: Screen shot showing that Xcode has been installled]

Comment: It's Xcode 8 now and *cannot* still isn't spelled correctly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Show the App Store's Debug menu (enter the following in Terminal):

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
   ```
2. Select Reset Application and restart the App Store

   [image]
3. Log in to the App Store through the Purchases tab.
4. Reboot.

Comment: Incredible. Perfect. Many thanks. I had no idea this was possible.

Comment: Worked for me for Xcode 7.0 without the reboot.  Many thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on 10.10.5 (14F27)

Comment: where did I get this menu showed in step 2.

Comment: @Suryakant From the Debug button in the menu bar, next to Window and Help.

Comment: Debug menu does not show up in Sierra, even after executing the `defaults`  command...

Comment: @NicolasMiari Did you got any alternative for that ! I also have Sierra and not able to display menu for me

Comment: Running `open /Applications/Xcode.app` from the command line worked for me on high sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how relevant this question is anymore, but I found it when I couldn't launch Xcode because it thought it was updating and continued thinking that even after a reboot.
I was able to solve it by clearing an extended attribute via this command:

```
sudo xattr -d com.apple.writer_bundle_identifier /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Not sure why it thought it was updating, there hasn't been an update for many weeks.